# Absurd movie from the 70s or early 80s about traveling in space

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

I watched an movie in the 90s about a man who was traveling in space:

- the man was alone in a spaceship
- seems like an employee of a cargo company, or something like that
- there was mechanical head built-in on board
- and they talk to each other about space and life time to time
- everything was getting meaningless, and absurd while going to such a far distance
- because traveling like that means wasting human life (time) also

Last sentence was the main theme of the movie, somewhat implied.

The movie looks like mostly black and white; but it was colorful, perhaps a 'b-movie' on VHS.

It was very interesting movie, I hope someone can identify it. Thanks.

Comment: Was the movie American, British, or otherwise?

Comment: Sounds like a bit like Moon.

Comment: It might be American

Comment: @Solemnity could you share an IMDB link? I would like it see, thank you--

Comment: [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1182345/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), but it won't be the specific movie you're looking for.  Too recent.

Comment: I can't place it but maybe you'll find it on Wikipedia's [List of Science Fiction Films of the 1970s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science-fiction_films_of_the_1970s) or [List of Science Fiction Films of the 1980s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science-fiction_films_of_the_1980s)

Comment: Are you sure it was a movie? It sounds a bit like the british comedy series [Red Dwarf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dwarf)

Comment: well, maybe, but I dont remember that series was aired on my country. Do you recognize that mechanical head built-in on board in that series?

Comment: @Digerkam, there was a robot named Kryten, and there were at least a couple of episodes where his head was not attached to his body for at least part of the show. There was also Holly, the ship computer, but his face showed up on a TV screen.

Comment: @TomHarrington It sounds very close, I've searched images, and videos, but couldnt see anything that shows Kryten's head deattached. The head that I mention mostly looks like the head which (I think) representing the Mother from the first Alien movie: http://2011upm59alien.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/capture-alien-1.jpg

Comment: @TomHarrington You describe the BBC television series "Red Dwarf". It's a comedy series. Not something philosophical as the question seems to imply.

Comment: @Tonny although it doesn't sound like Red Dwarf is the answer, I'd argue that the show is much more philosophical (at times, anyway) than the label "comedy" would imply. For example: what are the philosophical implications of meeting a duplicate of yourself with only your good qualities, or your bad ones? Red Dwarf goes there.

Comment: @TomHarrington It has it's moments, I agree with you on that. But in general the comedy is very dominant I would say. I like Red Dwarf precisely for this twisted take on serious matters, but most people won't even realize these themes are there in the show. They will just see the comedy.

Answer (score 5):

I'm probably wrong but it sounds like Silent Running   or possibly Darkstar

[Silentrunning 1972](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067756/plotsummary)

[Dark Star  1974](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069945/?ref_=sr_1)

Comment: Thank you! I know Dark Star. Silent Running was look interesting, but it is not what I am looking for. The man was always alone in the ship as I remember. And he was traviling in deep space, not in our solar system.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be an episode from a TV series, like *The Twilight Zone* episode "The Long Morrow"?

Comment: Very good point, but I dont think so, I am sure that it was a movie. But that episode was really very close. Thank you!